# How to obtain hostname and rename docker container on that?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose file for my backend service as follows.

```
backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/dev.Dockerfile
      # TODO: Try using cache_from pointed at a Docker Hub image built from master
      # Though may need to also use the workaround for local vs remote:
      # https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32612#issuecomment-294055017
      # cache_from: TODO
    image: treeherder-backend
    privileged: true
    environment:
      # Development/CI-specific environment variables only.
      # Those that do not vary across environments should go in `Dockerfile`.
      - BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq//
      - DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL:-mysql://root@mysql/treeherder}
      - GITHUB_TOKEN=${GITHUB_TOKEN:-}
      - UPSTREAM_DATABASE_URL=${UPSTREAM_DATABASE_URL:-}
      - PERF_SHERIFF_BOT_CLIENT_ID=${PERF_SHERIFF_BOT_CLIENT_ID:-}
      - PERF_SHERIFF_BOT_ACCESS_TOKEN=${PERF_SHERIFF_BOT_ACCESS_TOKEN:-}
      - PULSE_AUTO_DELETE_QUEUES=True
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
      - SITE_URL=http://backend:8000/
      - TREEHERDER_DEBUG=True
      - NEW_RELIC_INSIGHTS_API_KEY=${NEW_RELIC_INSIGHTS_API_KEY:-}
      - HOSTNAME=${HOSTNAME:-}
    entrypoint: './docker/entrypoint.sh'
    # We *ONLY* initialize the data when we're running the backend
    command: './initialize_data.sh ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    # Django's runserver doesn't listen to the default of SIGTERM, so docker-compose
    # must send SIGINT instead to avoid waiting 10 seconds for the time out.
    stop_signal: SIGINT
    # https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#running-the-images
    shm_size: 2g
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

I want to name this container dynamically by picking up the hostname on which it runs and rename itself on that value.
Kindly do let me know if there are any ways to do this

Current hostname of container - Random string by docker

The desired hostname of container - $(whoami)-$(hostname) of the host system on which this will run

Comment: Why?  (Can you share some relevant application code that uses it?)  The container's notion of its own hostname is rarely relevant to anything, and the default of the container ID is usually fine.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have a pulse queue exchange, whose name has to be unique. Right now I am using hostname (which is inside docker), so it gives random string. If I would be able to name my docker name on my host name, I would be able to uniquely identify it

Answer (score 0):

You can name your containers when you run them (you didn't specify how you run your containers, so I will assume you use `docker run`).

This is achieved using: `docker run -d --name YOUR_NAME YOUR_IMAGE`

This way you can have `YOUR_NAME` as a variable containing the fields you wanted, for example, running an `ubuntu:latest` container:

```sh
name=$(whoami)-$(uname -n)
docker run -d --name $name ubuntu:latest
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am looking for a way in which I could maybe access it from docker container itself and pass it as an env var

Comment: So you can still use `docker run -e HOST_HOSTNAME=hostname`